# How do I unit tests for Java classes that interact with a database, using a mock connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, mocking

Here's a little bit of background to give you some context to my question.

I am working on a project with a local company through my college, and the program that I am building must interact with a database and perform basic CRUD operations. The company is insisting that my code be unit tested and that I mock the connection to the database when performing unit tests. I have tried testing my code on a separate database but was told that doing this is an implementation test, not a unit test.

I have written a java class that contains methods which simply call and execute other `java.sql` methods, such as `createStatement()` and `executeUpdate(...)`, so that instead of writing four or five lines of code to interact with the database, I can just call another piece of code to automate it slightly for me. Here is an example of one of the methods within my class:

```
public boolean insertIntoTable(Connection connection, IQueryBuilder queryBuilder, String tableName, String[] dbFields, String[] dbFieldsValues) {
        String query = queryBuilder.insertIntoStatement(tableName, dbFields, dbFieldsValues);
        try {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            st.close();
            connection.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above `insertIntoTable` method only relies on two other pieces of code: `Connection` and `IQueryBuilder`. It returns true if all of the lines within the try execute without fail, and false otherwise.

`Connection` is an interface from the `java.sql` package, so we know that its method calls and implementations should work properly.

`IQueryBuilder` is another interface of mine that returns formatted SQL Strings which are intended to be be used by the `executeUpdate` method of the `Statement` interface. The implementation of IQueryBuilder that I will be using for this method has been unit tested and approved by the company, so I am assuming the passed implementation at this point functions properly as well.

Thus, we reach my question. How do I unit test something like `insertIntoTable` that doesn't necessarily have any business logic and must use a mock connection?

Furthermore, what exactly am I testing here? That the method returns true or false? I mock the connection to the database all I want, no problem. However, I feel that if I mock the connection to the database I'm not really testing anything, since there's no way to know if my code truly worked or not.

Comment: You’re right, I’m a big fan of unit tests, but mocking the jdbc objects is pointless. My preference would be use spring boot, where the framework handles the jdbc layer, and I write an integration test for each repository hitting an in memory h2 dB, and unit tests for the service layer that mock the repositories.

Comment: Btw the code posted has a connection leak.

Comment: Agreed with Nathan; in the real world, the answer is "use Spring Data, which creates your DAOs for you, and don't test generated code".

Comment: Thank you both for the insight. I will keep that in mind the next time I have to do something like this. Would you mind telling me where the leak is? It's not immediately apparent to me. I thought closing both the statement and the connection after preforming operations would prevent a leak

Comment: If you really need to unit test with a database, use something like [testcontainers-java](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to launch the actual database server for your tests.

Comment: about every method you call on a jdbc object can throw SQLException. in the code posted, if the update or statement close has something go wrong, an exception is thrown and close never gets called on the connection.